# Prevent UISegmentedControl from sending action method automatically

Tags: uikit, tvos

I'm programming an app for tvOS and am using a UISegmentedControl. My issue is that as I'm scrolling through items, it sends its action method as soon as I remain on an item for a second or two. I would like to disable this behaviour and rather fire the action only if user clicks it. 
Does anyone know how to do it?

Comment: Neither docs on [`UISegmentedContol`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uisegmentedcontrol) nor ones on [Segmented controls in general](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/UIKitUICatalog/UISegmentedControl.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012857-UISegmentedControl) mention anything like this. Do you have any unusual logic? What versions are involved?

Comment: Nothing unusual. The PrimaryAction is set in IB. Just tested in the latest tvOS.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my tvOS app and solved with this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var searchSegmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(didClickSegmentedSearchButton))
    tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}

func didClickSegmentedSearchButton() {
    switch searchSegmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0:
        // Restaurant
    case 1:
        // Hotel
    case 2:
        // Attraction
    case 3:
        // Shopping
    default:
        // Unknown
    }
}
```